# Android app ignore Raspberry PI Wifi AP.How to connect Android App to non internet Wifi network?

Tags: java, android, wifi

I have basic web view android app - client side, and Raspberry Pi as server side (NodeJS WEB server). Raspberry acts as Wifi access point and receive connections. Android app works when i have internet enabled on raspberry via lan port. When i try to connect and around me i have saved wifi connection wit INTERNET ACCESSS, app ignore raspberry pi wifi. How to force android app to connect to NON INTERNET WIFI and keep the connection?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to know, how you can prevent Android from switching networks, when the OS detects no Internet Connection.

You could start by disabling the Google Connectivity Services App. This sometimes works for me. To do this go to Settings -> Apps -> Google Connectivity Services (On some phones you need to enable 'system apps')

This feature might have different names on some brands...

Comment: Thank you but, i won't do it programmatically.